# Why doesn't the image in the UV Image Editor appear on the object in the 3D View in 2.8?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I can't figure out this problem.  Based on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM) video @ 1:59 (which, admittedly, is set up a little differently in terms of nodes), I should see the texture on the surface of the selected object...

[image]

Comment: You'll need a Texture Coordinate node as well if you want to use the UV map.

Comment: I had one; the results were no different.

Comment: ... and do what Jonney Shih wrote, select the Look Dev mode or texture in viewport shading. (I thought that was implied)

Comment: Was the texture coordinate node outputting with the uv option?

Answer (score 2):

Two ways I can think of:

1) In the viewport overlay settings on the top right, click on the down arrow to expand the shading settings, then check texture on the color group.
2) Or, even more simply switch to LookDev mode nearby to show applied textures on the material.

[image]

[image]